# Why do I get "error undeclared identifier" unless I declare my variable at the beginning?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

When I have following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

int val1,val2;

printf("Enter the first value");
scanf("%d",val1);
scanf("%d",&val2);
int c;
c=val1 + val2;
printf(" the value is : %d", c);



return 0; // 0 means no error

 }
```

I get error undeclared identifier c. Also, syntax error. missing ; before type.

However, if I change above to following error disappears. Please help

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

int val1,val2,c;

printf("Enter the first value");
scanf("%d",&val1);
scanf("%d",&val2);

c=val1 + val2;
printf(" the value is : %d", c);



return 0; // 0 means no error

}
```

I am running C in VS 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, at least back in the old days, variable declarations have to come at the top of the block.  C++ is different in that regard.

*edit* — apparently C99 is different from C90 in this respect (C99 being essentially the same as C++ on this issue).

Comment: VS2010 silently "broadens" the concept of a valid C program

Comment: @mbaitoff: VS2010 doesn't have the concept of a C program. It only compiles C++ programs. You need MinGW if you still want to compile C programs on Windows.

Comment: @Quandary: You can compile C Programs from VS 2010 command prompt. `cl hello.c` will give you `hello.exe`

Comment: @mbaitof:  Not true;  VC++ supports C compilation, and will use C compilation automatically for source files with a .c extension.  Just because the IDE does not offer .c as one of the preselected choices does not mean you cannot just create one. However VC++ *does not* support ISO C99, and Microsoft have no plans to do so.  It does however support elements of C99 that are also valid C++, so I believe that there may be an option to allow this, but it would be as easy to simply use C++ compilation.

Answer (score 3):

Objects may only be declared at the top of a statement block in ISO C90.  You can therefore do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int val1,val2;

    printf("Enter the first value");
    scanf("%d",val1);
    scanf("%d",&val2);

    // New statement block
    {
        int c;
        c=val1 + val2;
        printf(" the value is : %d", c);
    }

    return 0; // 0 means no error
 }
```

Though it would perhaps be unusual to do so.   Contrary to somewhat popular belief, the start of a function is not the only place you can declare an automatic variable.  It is more common, rather than creating a *dummy block*, to use existing statement blocks introduced as part of an `if` or `for` construct for example.

It is useful to enclose `case` blocks in { ... }, even though not normally necessary, so that you can introduce temporary case specific variables:

```
switch( x )
{
    case SOMETHING :
    {
        int case_local = 0 ;
    }
    break ;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C90, local variables must *all* be declared at the beginning of a <s>function</s> block.

Comment: In fact they need only be declared at the beginning of a *statement block*.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft decided against supporting newer revisions of the C language, so you can't mix code and declarations. With MSVC, you're basically stuck with C90, although some selected features  (eg `long long`, `restrict`) are supported.

My recommendation would be to either switch to C++ or use a different compiler like the [MinGW edition of GCC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/).

Answer (score 0):

One other observation. scanf() wants the ADDRESS of the destination, not it's value.

in the top example you are omitting the **&** in  **scanf("%d",val1);** . In the bottom example it is included **scanf("%d",&val1);**

"val1" vs "&val1"

Shouldn't change the problem with the variable 'c', but probably causing a syntax error somewhere?