# Why do I get undeclared identifier error when I create variables dynamically?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774961/why-do-i-get-error-undeclared-identifier-unless-i-declare-my-variable-at-the-b) and I noticed that I get errors when I declare variables in the middle of the `main()` function, but I thought that creating variables dynamically wouldn't cause an error, because it can be done anywhere and anytime during run-time (as far as I know).

However, I still get:

```
error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'z' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'intArr' : undeclared identifier
```

My code:

```
int main()
{
  ..... 
  .....
  ..... 

  printf("Type the array size:\t");
  int *z = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  scanf("%d", z);
  int *intArr = (int *)malloc((*z) * sizeof(int));

  int *i = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));

  for (*i = 0; *i < *z; ((*i)++))
  {
      printf("Type a number\t");
      scanf("%d", (intArr+(*i)));
  }

  printArr(intArr);
}

void printArr(int *arr)
{
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)); ++i)
        printf("%d ", *(arr+i));
}
```

Comment: It is one of the differences between the C89 and C99 standards.  MSVC doesn't support C99.

Comment: What Hans said, but note, when compiling C files as C files. Compiling everything as C++ obviously changes that. It is a configurable option in the MSVC compiler settings whether to compile C as C++ or C.

Comment: @Hans Does MSVC actually support all of C89? It was my impression that it doesn’t really support C at all, just a subset of C++ which Microsoft insists on calling “C” but which really is just a reduced feature set.

Comment: Side notes: 1. Do you have to allocate `z` and `i` dynamically? They look like simple size and loop variables! 2. If you do, you should also `free` them. 3. `type *var = malloc(size * sizeof(*var));` is much more maintainable as you don't repeat `type` over and over again.

Comment: @Shahbaz I did that because I thought it would allow me to declare variables in the middle of the function (but it looks like it has nothing to do with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not sure why @Blood deleted his answer; it was essentially correct.)

When I compile your program using gcc, it compiles with no errors.  I had to add

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
```

to the top, and delete the three `.....` lines.

When I compile the same program using Microsoft's Visual C++ 2010 Express, I get a number of errors. Several of them complain about undeclared identifiers, but that's a common side effect of syntax errors; if the compiler can't parse your source file, it's likely to become "confused" as it tries to recover.  The most relevant error is:

```
syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
```

on line 10:

```
printf("Type the array size:\t");     // line 9
int *z = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));  // line 10
```

The problem is that the 1989/1990 version of the C standard doesn't permit mixing declarations and statements within a block; it requires all declarations to appear first, followed by all statements.  The 1999 C standard changed that, but Microsoft's C compiler has very limited support for any C standard past the 1990 one (and they've said they have no intention of changing that).  (I expect they *might* permit mixed declarations and statements in a future version, since that's a C++ feature as well.)

(I'm assuming from the form of the error messages that you're using a Microsoft compiler.)

You can rearrange your code to satisfy the Microsoft compiler's restrictions. In some cases, you might need to change something like

```
int *var = initial_value;
```

to

```
int *var;
// ...
var = initial_value;
```

Another suggestion, not related to your question:

In C, you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()`. The `malloc()` function returns a value of type `void*`, which can be *implicitly* converted to any pointer-to-object type. (C++ doesn't have this implicit conversion, but you probably shouldn't be using `malloc()` in C++ anyway.)

Rather than this:

```
int *z = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
...
int *intArr = (int *)malloc((*z) * sizeof(int));
```

you can write this:

```
int *z = malloc(sizeof *z);
...
int *intArr = malloc(*z * sizeof *intArr);
```

Dropping the unnecessary cast can avoid certain errors; for example, with some compilers a cast can mask a necessary error message if you've forgotten the required `#include <stdlib.h>`. And applying `sizeof` to `*z` or `*intArr`, rather than naming the size explicitly, means that you won't have to change the call if the type of the pointer changes. If you write, for example:

```
double *p = malloc(sizeof (int)); // incorrect
```

then you're allocating the wrong size, but the compiler won't warn you about it.

Also, if you're allocating a single `int` value using `malloc()`, as you're doing with your `i` and `z` pointers, you're doing unnecessary work. Unless your purpose is to practice using `malloc()`, you might as well just make `i` and `z` `int` variables, and drop the `malloc()` calls. You'll just have to pass their *addresses* to `scanf`. In other words, you can change this:

```
int *z = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
...
scanf("%d", z);
```

to this:

```
int z;
...
scanf("%d", &z);
```

One more point: your program has no error checking. `malloc()` can fail if there isn't enough memory to allocate; it returns a null pointer (`NULL`) when this happens. `scanf()` can fail if there's an input error, or if you type `hello` when it's expecting to read an `int`. `scanf()` returns the number of items it successfully scanned; you should verify that it did so (in this case, it returns 1 on success). For a simple program like this, aborting the program with an error message:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Call to ... failed\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

is probably good enough.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I learned a lot from it. I am currently using Microsoft's Visual C++ 2010 Express. Do you think I should use GCC to compile my code instead? I like programming in Visual Studio.